# Should ViewModels contain Property Values against Property IDs in the Entity (Model Class)?

Tags: c#, automapper, viewmodel

So I have CityID (property) in my Interview Entity/Model.

Can(should) I have CityName in my ViewModel (InterviewViewModel.cs)?

If yes, how would I map them using AutoMapper since it (City) is a separate Entity?

```
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
        cfg.CreateMap<Interview, InterviewViewModel>()
        .ForMember
            (dst => dst.CityName, src => src.MapFrom (e => e. // how would I do this?? ))

        });
```

Comment: Create a city property in Interview and do e=> e.City.CityName, you are using ORM think that way.

Comment: You mean a navigational property right? I thought of this, but then I would need City in other entities too. Then I would have to have ICollection<City>Cities in all those entites, right? 
Also, then I would need a CityID also in my Interview to store the City associated with Interview...?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And that's the way to go and how it should be done. If you don't want to do that then you will need to map the city name manually, by querying the City table. That will be two db calls, and not much efficient.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plase create a `City` navigation property in `Interview` and do `e=> e.City.CityName` in automapper conifg.

It will make things easier and you will be able to utilize the full potential of Entity Framework or other ORM you are using. Other wise you will need to manually query the `City` table and then add the name to you `Interview ViewModel`.